# count where value not in another table without '-' mysql

Tags: mysql, replace

**Question:** I need to count the rows that are not in `table2` by phone, I have two tables

**Description:** `table1` has column phone, `table2` has also column `phone`. 
The problem is that sometimes the column `phone` may contain '-' and I want to remove it so I can compare and count if it doesn't exist in `table1`. example:

```
table1          table2 
id phone       id phone 
1 01-123       1  01123
2 12345        2  23456
```

The expected result count needs to be 1 . 
So far I wrote this query, but it's not working, any help?

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table1  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE REPLACE(table1.phone, '-', '') = REPLACE(table2.telephone, '-', ''))
```

Answer (score 2):

You must try `NOT IN`

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM   table1 
WHERE  phone NOT IN (SELECT Replace(telephone, '-', '') 
                     FROM   table2);
```

[**See it in Action**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d316e/2)

Comment: Really Great piece or research when the same is answered 7 mins earlier. I like your answer specially the 'telephone' part

Comment: @MySQLRockstar You can't judge answer by similarity, it should be depend of correct desired output. Let Community decide this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, only if table2.phone got '-' and table1.phone doesn't have that

```
   SELECT count(*) FROM table1 
    WHERE phone NOT IN
      (SELECT REPLACE(phone, '-', '') from table2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

100 % working

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table1 WHERE phone NOT IN(SELECT REPLACE(phone, '-', '') from table2 );
```

Comment: 100%? What happens if a phone number in table2 contains a hyphen?

Comment: oh this is the same copy paste of my answer (though not correct)